# The mandatory attribute 'lightbox' is missing in tag AMP-CAROUSEL

Tags: html, amp-html

I can't seem to find any information about how to use the lightbox attribute on the AMP-CAROUSEL tag in AMP pages..

Google Web Master tools obviously think this is invalid AMP syntax so why isn't there any documentation about this lightbox attribute and how to use it?

[image]

Even their samples have it missing?
https://ampbyexample.com/advanced/image_galleries_with_amp-carousel/

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you are correct `image_galleries_with_amp-carousel` it is not there. In palce of this You can use `amp-lightbox-gallery` and `amp-carousel`

**amp-lightbox** : The amp-lightbox-gallery component provides a "lightbox” experience for AMP components (e.g., amp-img, amp-carousel). When the user interacts with the AMP element, a UI component expands to fill the viewport until it is closed by the user. Currently, only images are supported.

For more details [click here](https://ampbyexample.com/components/amp-lightbox-gallery/)

[**Here is working URL**](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/vrVGLr)

**CODE :**

```
<!doctype html>
<html ⚡>
 <head>
   <meta charset="utf-8">
   <link rel="canonical" href="amp-lightbox-gallery-with-carousel.html">
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,minimum-scale=1,initial-scale=1">
   <style amp-boilerplate>body{-webkit-animation:-amp-start 8s steps(1,end) 0s 1 normal both;-moz-animation:-amp-start 8s steps(1,end) 0s 1 normal both;-ms-animation:-amp-start 8s steps(1,end) 0s 1 normal both;animation:-amp-start 8s steps(1,end) 0s 1 normal both}@-webkit-keyframes -amp-start{from{visibility:hidden}to{visibility:visible}}@-moz-keyframes -amp-start{from{visibility:hidden}to{visibility:visible}}@-ms-keyframes -amp-start{from{visibility:hidden}to{visibility:visible}}@-o-keyframes -amp-start{from{visibility:hidden}to{visibility:visible}}@keyframes -amp-start{from{visibility:hidden}to{visibility:visible}}</style><noscript><style amp-boilerplate>body{-webkit-animation:none;-moz-animation:none;-ms-animation:none;animation:none}</style></noscript>
    <script async src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0.js"></script>
    <script async custom-element="amp-lightbox-gallery" src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0/amp-lightbox-gallery-0.1.js"></script>
    <script async custom-element="amp-carousel" src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0/amp-carousel-0.1.js"></script>
    <style amp-custom>
    .wrapper { width:600px; margin:0 auto; }
    .overlay-text {
      position: absolute;
      bottom: 16px;
      left: 16px;
      z-index: 1;
      pointer-events: none;
      background-color: #494A4D;
      color: white;
      padding: 2px 6px 2px 6px;
      border-radius: 2px;
      opacity: 0.7;
      font-family: Roboto, sans-serif;
      font-size: 1em;
    }
    amp-img[lightbox] {
      cursor: pointer;
    }
  </style>
    <title>AMP Lightbox Gallery with Carousel</title>
 </head>
 <body>
 <div class="wrapper">
    <amp-carousel controls lightbox width="400" height="400" layout="responsive" type="slides">
      <amp-img src="https://dummyimage.com/600x400/F00/FFF" width="400" height="400" layout="responsive"></amp-img>
      <amp-img src="https://dummyimage.com/600x400/FF0/FFF" width="400" height="400" layout="responsive"></amp-img>
      <amp-img src="https://dummyimage.com/600x400/00F/FFF" width="400" height="400" layout="responsive"></amp-img>
    </amp-carousel>
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```